# Play wave file using AudioFormat in java

Tags: java, audio

I m getting following exception while running my code on linux operating system.This code works fine on windows operating system.below is the exception and code used.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface Clip supporting format PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian is supported.

```
AudioFormat format = sourceaudio.getFormat();

format = new AudioFormat(
    AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                format.getSampleRate(),
                format.getSampleSizeInBits() * 2,
                format.getChannels(),
                format.getFrameSize() * 2,
                format.getFrameRate(),
                true);

AudioFileFormat.Type targettype = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
AudioInputStream targetaudiostream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(format, sourceaudio);

sourceaudio.close();
targetaudiostream.close();
System.out.println("55555555");

URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/newvideo/PCMfile.wav");
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
clip.open(ais);

System.out.println("seconds: " + (clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000000));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error on windows when audio devices are disabled in "device manager". I think the problem is - audio device driver, try to update or reinstall it.